# I am implementing ads in my flutter app using Applovin, anytime I run the app I get this error

Tags: flutter, applovin

I integrated AppLovin into my flutter app 2 months ago and it was working fine.
Last week I tried running the app and am getting this error.

```
C:\Flutter sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_applovin_max-2.1.2\android\src\main\java\dev\iori\flutter_applovin_max\FlutterApplovinMaxPlugin.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
                    AppLovinPrivacySettings.setHasUserConsent( call.argument("HasConsent"), context );
                    ^
  symbol:   variable AppLovinPrivacySettings
  location: class FlutterApplovinMaxPlugin
C:\Flutter sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_applovin_max-2.1.2\android\src\main\java\dev\iori\flutter_applovin_max\FlutterApplovinMaxPlugin.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
                    AppLovinPrivacySettings.setIsAgeRestrictedUser( call.argument("IsAgeRestricted"), context );
                    ^
  symbol:   variable AppLovinPrivacySettings
  location: class FlutterApplovinMaxPlugin
C:\Flutter sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_applovin_max-2.1.2\android\src\main\java\dev\iori\flutter_applovin_max\FlutterApplovinMaxPlugin.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
                    AppLovinPrivacySettings.setDoNotSell( call.argument("DoNotSell"), context );
                    ^
  symbol:   variable AppLovinPrivacySettings
  location: class FlutterApplovinMaxPlugin
Note: C:\Flutter sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_applovin_max-2.1.2\android\src\main\java\dev\iori\flutter_applovin_max\FlutterApplovinMaxPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_applovin_max:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 51s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific  technical issue.

Comment: @Desmond, did you find a solution? I've got the same problem?

Comment: Yes, use this package https://pub.dev/packages/applovin_max

Answer (score 0):

Use this [applovin_max](https://pub.dev/packages/applovin_max) plugin, it's the official AppLovin Max's Flutter plugin according to [flutter_applovin_max's](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_applovin_max) documentation.